# iPhone development using flash

Tags: iphone, flash-cs5

I'm looking to develop an iphone app using flash. I understand Apple are allowing apps made using flash into the appstore...

I don't own a mac, I'd be doing this on Windows. But to get it to the appstore, I'd need to enroll as a registered developer.

Before I spend money to do this, can I a) upload test apps via Windows? b) submit to apple from windows?

Thanks

James.

Answer (score 0):

No to both of those (AFAIK). I think you will need a mac to upload your app to itunes connect.

I'm also pretty sure that the toolkits that build flash iPhone apps will use the command line compiler from a mac as well to build the final binary so I'm not sure that you can even develop the app without a mac.

Sorry for the bad news :(

PS I'd love someone to correct my answer - I'd like people to be able to build on any platform they wanted but I can also see why apple don't want this :)

Comment: Stop the press, this link suggests that you can!! 

"Developing iOS Applications on Windows"
http://gotoandlearn.com/play?id=116